# To get data of authenticated user failure

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
public void loadUserInformation() {

    final String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
//        DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("ref").child(uid);
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String name=postSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
//                    String email=postSnapshot.child("Email").getValue().toString();

                Name.setText(name);

//                    Email.setText(email);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Loading UserDetails",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

I know why I'm not getting the expected results, its because there's one more child after users. I'm not sure on how to access it, child(uid) gave me a `NullPointerException`. The present code gives me name of some random user. I want it to return name of the authenticated user i.e. myself

Database - http://ibb.co/iRnF77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the phone number to the userid:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
```

So you will have this database:

```
Users
  userid
    Name: namehere
    Phone_Number: numberhere
    //etc
```

then you can simply retrieve the data of the current user:

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid);

ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name=dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();                     


            Name.setText(name);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

You don't need the phone number to be the parent node since you already have it as an attribute `Phone_Number: number_here`, no need to write it twice.

Also `getPhoneNumber()` can be used if you did phone authentication:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Comment: i did use phone authentication... also getuid returns uid but i dont hav uid in my code so it returning null

Comment: when you use phone authentication, the user will have a unique uid for him also

Comment: yeah but uid with return uid... it wont return phone number

Comment: yes that is what I mean, it is better to use the `uid` as a parent node of each record and then inside you have `phone_number`